# Flex : Communicate between the skin and the data model?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

How to send to the skin some value which have changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two approaches to this: one uses binding and is easier, the other is more complex but better for performance.

**Using binding**

Suppose your view class looks like this:

```
public class MyClass extends SkinnableComponent {
    [Bindable] public var myValue:String;
}
```

then you can bind to that value in your skin like this:

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("MyClass")]
    </fx:Metadata>

   <s:Label id="myLabel" text="{hostComponent.myValue}" />

</s:Skin>
```

**Overriding commitProperties**

Assume the same skin without the binding, then you can set the label's text property by using a skinpart and overriding commitProperties in the host component. The skinpart's name must be exactly the same as the id of the component in the skin (in this case 'myLabel').

```
public class MyClass extends SkinnableComponent {

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var myLabel:Label;

    public var myValue:String;

    override protected function commitProperties():void {
        if (myLabel) myLabel.text = myValue;
        super.commitProperties();
    }
}
```

Of course you would have to call `invalidateProperties()` whenever you want to apply the new value (for instance in a setter function for 'myLabel'). Also notice that 'myLabel' no longer needs to be bindable, unless you would want to be able to bind on it externally.

---

edit: **which approach to choose?**

I have just answered a question that is closely related to this one in which I elaborate on the pro's and cons of each approach in different situations. You can find it here: [Flex: Additional label in ButtonBarButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390523/flex-additional-label-in-buttonbarbutton)